# Select node with xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I want to go to a deep link for the xml with xpath, and also there is a name space in it. Currently I have:

```
XmlNode link = xmlDoc
    .SelectSingleNode("dn:feed", nsmgr)
    .SelectSingleNode("dn:entry", nsmgr)
    .SelectSingleNode("dn:link", nsmgr);
```

This works fine, but since the path is very long I just want to use kind of xpath like:

```
XmlNode link = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("dn:feed/entry/link", nsmgr);
```

But this does not works.

Comment: `But this does not works.` Can you give us a bit more to go off of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is a namespace problem. You're only specifying the namespace for the `feed` element, not for `entry` or `link`. Try this:

```
XmlNode link = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("dn:feed/dn:entry/dn:link", nsmgr);
```

Personally I'd use LINQ to XML if possible though - aside from being a generally nicer API than `XmlDocument`, it makes it really easy to work with namespaces:

```
XDocument doc = ...;
XNamespace dn = "...";
XElement link = doc.Element(dn + "feed")
                   .Element(dn + "entry")
                   .Element(dn + "link");
```

I prefer expressing what I'm looking for (attributes, elements etc, with conditions where appropriate) in code rather than in XPath. Your mileage may vary, of course.

Comment: Yes, Xpath can be quite tricky and a 'language' of its own where as LINQ is used everywhere in .NET